# pgfplots : Box Plots and two y axis

Tags: pgfplots, boxplot

I'm trying to add some data points on another y axis along with box plots.
My experience in TeX is quite limited and I'm not sure why my axis appears in the middle of my x axis instead of at the end and why the data points are not using the same x coordinates of my first axis. The label of my two y axis are also superposed..

I'm using code from an example for the box plots so I'm still working my way to understand it all while fiddling with it.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

%testdata.dat   index median box_top box_bottom whisker_top whisker_bottom 


\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
1   0.63    0.76125 0.4025  0.81833 0.15333 0.55627
2   0.65333 0.71667 0.44333 0.82    0.03333 0.55492
3   0.5075  0.70417 0.37333 0.785   0.14667 0.50746
4   0.53333 0.75375 0.38333 0.82167 0.13833 0.53283
5   0.55667 0.64625 0.33167 0.77667 0   0.48992
6   0.53167 0.70333 0.41333 0.78833 0   0.50817
7   0.57833 0.73417 0.46167 0.81833 0.27667 0.57833
8   0.43    0.58417 0.31917 0.7 0.08333 0.43983
9   0.4375  0.61083 0.32    0.71    0   0.43458
10  0.6475  0.82167 0.54042 0.97333 0.02667 0.63617
11  0.70667 0.90542 0.61083 1.04    0.29333 0.72058
12  0.62    0.80958 0.53167 0.99667 0   0.61792
13  0.73333 0.90583 0.63667 0.98333 0.12333 0.71158
14  0.66833 0.8375  0.58833 0.93667 0.08    0.66208
15  0.54833 0.69167 0.44917 0.80333 0.10333 0.52114
16  0.545   0.72917 0.45375 0.87667 0.07333 0.53933
17  0.6175  0.72583 0.4875  0.87    0.13    0.57375
18  0.66333 0.79917 0.57    0.98333 0.21    0.6495
19  0.79167 0.88417 0.68667 0.96667 0.04333 0.71367
20  0.75833 0.89667 0.69917 1.00667 0.03667 0.73283
21  0.89    0.96917 0.82292 1.12    0.24    0.85858
22  0.79333 0.91417 0.71333 1.03    0.07667 0.76858



\end{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{
 box plot width/.initial=1em,
 box plot/.style={
    /pgfplots/.cd,
    black,
    only marks,
    mark=-,
    mark size=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/box plot width},
    /pgfplots/error bars/.cd,
    y dir=plus,
    y explicit,
 },
 box plot box/.style={
    /pgfplots/error bars/draw error bar/.code 2 args={densely dashed%
        \draw  ##1 -- ++(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/box plot width},0pt) |- ##2 -- ++(-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/box plot width},0pt) |- ##1 -- cycle;
    },
    /pgfplots/table/.cd,
    y index=2,
    y error expr={\thisrowno{3}-\thisrowno{2}},
    /pgfplots/box plot
 },
 box plot top whisker/.style={
    /pgfplots/error bars/draw error bar/.code 2 args={%
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/error bars/error mark}%
        {\pgfplotserrorbarsmark}%
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/error bars/error mark options}%
        {\pgfplotserrorbarsmarkopts}%
        \path ##1 -- ##2;
    },
    /pgfplots/table/.cd,
    y index=4,
    y error expr={\thisrowno{2}-\thisrowno{4}},
    /pgfplots/box plot
 },
 box plot bottom whisker/.style={
    /pgfplots/error bars/draw error bar/.code 2 args={%
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/error bars/error mark}%
        {\pgfplotserrorbarsmark}%
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/error bars/error mark options}%
        {\pgfplotserrorbarsmarkopts}%
        \path ##1 -- ##2;
    },
    /pgfplots/table/.cd,
    y index=5,
    y error expr={\thisrowno{3}-\thisrowno{5}},
    /pgfplots/box plot
 },
 box plot median/.style={densely dotted,
    /pgfplots/box plot
 }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
   ymin=0,
   xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22}, 
   scale only axis,
   axis y line*=left,
   xlabel=Campagnes,
   ylabel=CCRL (mg/L),
   box plot width=0.5em, 
   x=0.5cm,
   enlarge x limits=0.05,
   y tick label style={
 /pgf/number format/.cd,
    fixed,
    fixed zerofill,
    precision=2}
]
 \addplot [box plot median] table {testdata.dat};
 \addplot [box plot box] table {testdata.dat};
 \addplot [box plot top whisker] table {testdata.dat};
 \addplot [box plot bottom whisker] table {testdata.dat};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis} [
   scale only axis,
   axis y line*=right,
    axis x line=none, 
    xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22}, 
   ylabel={Temp\'erature}]
\addplot [only marks,mark=square] coordinates{(1,6.7) (2,9.1) (3,10.7) (4,13.6) (5,14) (6,13.6) (7,15.4) (8,16.9) (9,18.3)       (10,18.1) (11,19.1) (12,19.7) (13,19.7) (14,20.6) (15,21) (16,20) (17,20.1) (18,20.4) (19,19.3) (20,18) (21,17.3) (22,15.6)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/9PPksA4.png]

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that both your axes have the same width. In this case, that means that you also need to put the `x=0.5cm, enlarge x limits=0.05` that you use in the first axis into the options for the second axis. To get the label right, set `compat=1.8` or newer:

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

%testdata.dat   index median box_top box_bottom whisker_top whisker_bottom 


\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
1   0.63    0.76125 0.4025  0.81833 0.15333 0.55627
2   0.65333 0.71667 0.44333 0.82    0.03333 0.55492
3   0.5075  0.70417 0.37333 0.785   0.14667 0.50746
4   0.53333 0.75375 0.38333 0.82167 0.13833 0.53283
5   0.55667 0.64625 0.33167 0.77667 0   0.48992
6   0.53167 0.70333 0.41333 0.78833 0   0.50817
7   0.57833 0.73417 0.46167 0.81833 0.27667 0.57833
8   0.43    0.58417 0.31917 0.7 0.08333 0.43983
9   0.4375  0.61083 0.32    0.71    0   0.43458
10  0.6475  0.82167 0.54042 0.97333 0.02667 0.63617
11  0.70667 0.90542 0.61083 1.04    0.29333 0.72058
12  0.62    0.80958 0.53167 0.99667 0   0.61792
13  0.73333 0.90583 0.63667 0.98333 0.12333 0.71158
14  0.66833 0.8375  0.58833 0.93667 0.08    0.66208
15  0.54833 0.69167 0.44917 0.80333 0.10333 0.52114
16  0.545   0.72917 0.45375 0.87667 0.07333 0.53933
17  0.6175  0.72583 0.4875  0.87    0.13    0.57375
18  0.66333 0.79917 0.57    0.98333 0.21    0.6495
19  0.79167 0.88417 0.68667 0.96667 0.04333 0.71367
20  0.75833 0.89667 0.69917 1.00667 0.03667 0.73283
21  0.89    0.96917 0.82292 1.12    0.24    0.85858
22  0.79333 0.91417 0.71333 1.03    0.07667 0.76858



\end{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{
 box plot width/.initial=1em,
 box plot/.style={
    /pgfplots/.cd,
    black,
    only marks,
    mark=-,
    mark size=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/box plot width},
    /pgfplots/error bars/.cd,
    y dir=plus,
    y explicit,
 },
 box plot box/.style={
    /pgfplots/error bars/draw error bar/.code 2 args={densely dashed%
        \draw  ##1 -- ++(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/box plot width},0pt) |- ##2 -- ++(-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/box plot width},0pt) |- ##1 -- cycle;
    },
    /pgfplots/table/.cd,
    y index=2,
    y error expr={\thisrowno{3}-\thisrowno{2}},
    /pgfplots/box plot
 },
 box plot top whisker/.style={
    /pgfplots/error bars/draw error bar/.code 2 args={%
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/error bars/error mark}%
        {\pgfplotserrorbarsmark}%
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/error bars/error mark options}%
        {\pgfplotserrorbarsmarkopts}%
        \path ##1 -- ##2;
    },
    /pgfplots/table/.cd,
    y index=4,
    y error expr={\thisrowno{2}-\thisrowno{4}},
    /pgfplots/box plot
 },
 box plot bottom whisker/.style={
    /pgfplots/error bars/draw error bar/.code 2 args={%
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/error bars/error mark}%
        {\pgfplotserrorbarsmark}%
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/error bars/error mark options}%
        {\pgfplotserrorbarsmarkopts}%
        \path ##1 -- ##2;
    },
    /pgfplots/table/.cd,
    y index=5,
    y error expr={\thisrowno{3}-\thisrowno{5}},
    /pgfplots/box plot
 },
 box plot median/.style={densely dotted,
    /pgfplots/box plot
 }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
   ymin=0,
   xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22}, 
   scale only axis,
   axis y line*=left,
   xlabel=Campagnes,
   ylabel=CCRL (mg/L),
   box plot width=0.5em, 
   x=0.5cm,
   enlarge x limits=0.05,
   y tick label style={
 /pgf/number format/.cd,
    fixed,
    fixed zerofill,
    precision=2}
]
 \addplot [box plot median] table {testdata.dat};
 \addplot [box plot box] table {testdata.dat};
 \addplot [box plot top whisker] table {testdata.dat};
 \addplot [box plot bottom whisker] table {testdata.dat};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis} [
   scale only axis,
   axis y line*=right,
    axis x line=none, 
    x=0.5cm,
    enlarge x limits=0.05,
    xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22}, 
   ylabel={Temp\'erature}]
\addplot [only marks,mark=square*, red] coordinates{(1,6.7) (2,9.1) (3,10.7) (4,13.6) (5,14) (6,13.6) (7,15.4) (8,16.9) (9,18.3)       (10,18.1) (11,19.1) (12,19.7) (13,19.7) (14,20.6) (15,21) (16,20) (17,20.1) (18,20.4) (19,19.3) (20,18) (21,17.3) (22,15.6)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```